# Test for one coefficient doubled another one?

Tags: regression, contrasts

I want to run a regression in order to test ( thinking of the $t$-test ) the null hypothesis that one coefficient ($b_2$) is twice another coefficient ($b_3$), so $b_2= 2 b_3$, The variable for $b_3$ is a dummy variable. The $t$-test is $(b_2-2b_3)/se(b_2-2b_3)$. How can I find $se(b_2-2b_3)$?

Comment: You can just report likelihood ratio of your hypothesis to alternative.

Comment: What are you using to do your stats?

Answer (score 3):

Most any statistics package will report, somewhere, the covariance matrix of your estimators. Let $S$ denote this covariance matrix.

Let $w = \left[ \begin{array}{c}1\\-2\end{array} \right]$ and $b = \left[ \begin{array}{c}b_1\\b_2\end{array} \right]$

$\mathrm{Var}(w'b) = w'\mathrm{Var}(b)w = w'Sw$. The standard error of $w'b$ would then be $\sqrt{w'Sw}$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by MatthewGunn applies more generally. If you are working under the framework of linear regression (or generalized linear regression), then

$$se(b_2 - 2b_3) = \sqrt{\dfrac{Var(b_2 - 2b_3)}{n}},$$

where $n$ is the number of observations. The covariance matrix of regression coefficients is $\sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1}$, which can be calculates for every problem.

$$Var(b_2 - 2b_3) = Var(b_2) + 4Var(b_3) - 4Cov(b_2, b_3).$$

These values can be picked from the estimate of $\sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1}$. For example, in `R` you can use the `vcov` function on the `lm` object. I present the example on the dataset `cars` below.

```
> fit <- lm(cars)
> vcov(fit)
            (Intercept)          dist
(Intercept)  0.76454824 -0.0131543211
dist        -0.01315432  0.0003060568
```

Here $Var(dist - 2Intercept)$ = .0003 + 4(.76454) - 4(-.01315).

Comment: (+1) Perhaps worth noting that the likelihood-ratio test may be preferable for generalized linear models: compare the model having $b_1x_1 + b_2x_2$ with the restricted one having $b(x_1+2x_2)$.